# Code does not seem to pass a certain line, causing StackOverflowException

Tags: c#, linq

I have this small piece of code that compares the types of 2 variables and then returns a certain output if they are equal or not. Code is below:

```
public new bool Equals(object x, object y)
    {
        var xType = x.GetType();
        var yType = y.GetType();
        if (xType != yType) return false;

        return GetPropertiesWithoutKey(xType).All(pd => Comparer.IsPropertyChanged(pd, x, y));
    }
```

While debugging I've put a breakpoint on 'return GetPropertiesWithoutKey(...)' but after it hits the line it won't go past it. Even after hitting F10 and F5 several times. After removing the breakpoint and hitting F10 or F5, I get a StackOverflow Exception.

Does anyone know why this happens?

Questions, remarks and suggestions are always welcome.

Kind regards

EDIT 1: The code for GetPropertiesWithoutKey(...)

```
private IList<PropertyDescriptor> GetPropertiesWithoutKey(Type entityType)
    {
        return _syncProperties ??
               (_syncProperties = GetEntityTypeDescriptor(entityType).Properties.Where(el => !el.IsKey).ToList());
    }
```

EDIT 2: The code for Comparer.IsPropertyChanged(...)

```
public static bool IsPropertyChanged(PropertyDescriptor pd, object entity1, object entity2)
    {
        object val1 = null;
        object val2 = null;
        if ((typeof(ICollection).IsAssignableFrom(pd.PropertyInfo.PropertyType)
            && entity1 != null
            && ((ICollection)entity1).Count != 0)
            || (!typeof(ICollection).IsAssignableFrom(pd.PropertyInfo.PropertyType)
            && entity1 != null))
        {
            val1 = entity1;
            //val1 = pd.PropertyInfo.GetValue(entity1);
        }

        if ((typeof(ICollection).IsAssignableFrom(pd.PropertyInfo.PropertyType)
             && entity2 != null
             && ((ICollection)entity2).Count != 0)
             || (!typeof(ICollection).IsAssignableFrom(pd.PropertyInfo.PropertyType)
             && entity2 != null))
        {
            val2 = entity2;
            //val2 = pd.PropertyInfo.GetValue(entity2);
        }

        if (val1 == null && val2 == null)
        {
            return false;
        }
        if (val1 == null || val2 == null)
        {
            return true;
        }
        if (typeof(ICollection).IsAssignableFrom(pd.PropertyInfo.PropertyType))
        {
            return IsCollectionChanged(pd, val1, val2);
        }
        if (!pd.PropertyInfo.PropertyType.IsPrimitive || !(pd.PropertyInfo.PropertyType == typeof(String)))
        {
            return IsComplexChanged(pd, val1, val2); //<-- Debugger gets here (EDIT 3)
        }

        if (val1 != null)
        {
            return !val1.Equals(val2);
        }
        else if (val2 != null)
        {
            return !val2.Equals(val1);
        }
        return false;
    }
```

EDIT 3: Code for IsComplexChanged

```
private static bool IsComplexChanged(PropertyDescriptor pd, object val1, object val2)
    {
        var comparer = new EqualityComparer();
        return !comparer.Equals(val1, val2); //<-- This line refers back to Equals function
    }
```

As you can see in the last edit I have found where the loop is being made.

First a function GetChangedProperties() calls on Comparer.IsPropertyChanged, in IsPropertyChanged debugger always goes as far as Comparer.IsComplexChanged and this refers to Equals. 
In the lambda expression in Equals in the GetPropertiesWithoutKey(...), Comparer.IsPropertyChanged is calles which then creates the loop. I have written down a schedule of the steps taken.

If anyone wants to see this just ask and I'll take a picture of it.

I hope someone might know a solution or can help me get started on fixing the problem, your help is greatly appreciated because I'm drawing a blank right now.

Any further questions are always welcome

Comment: Post the code for `GetPropertiesWithoutKey` it likely has some kind of infinite recursion going on.

Comment: Or Comparer.IsPropertyChanged uses the Equals method in which it is called.

Comment: In many coding languages, Equals() is an existing method. So maybe you overrode that method and kept calling it. Try changing your method's name.

Comment: I have added the code that Ben Robinson and galenus requested, I still have to see what happens when I change the method name, I'll keep you posted

Comment: Trying to rename the Equals() method gives a message that says 'The member <member> was defined in a referenced assembly. Renaming its references will result in build errors.

Comment: Any particularly relevant reason why your `Equals` implementation is `new` instead of `override`?

Comment: At run time, can you tell what is the actual types of `x` and `y` inside the `Equals(object x, object y)` implementation? If so, could you please share that type's implementation of the `Equals(object obj)` override, or the first such override found up its class hierarchy?

Comment: @EmreAcar After renaming the method and solving the build errors the same problem still occurs :-/

Comment: @LeandroTaset, I don't know. I recently got put on this project so I don't know everything about it yet, let me try to see what override gives. And I'll come back with the type of the objects in a couple minutes.

Comment: IT seems likely that its not that it won't go past the line "GetPropertiesWithoutKey" but that you are getting back there again and again, likely because something is calling back into your equals method. After hitting F5 a couple of times with the breakpoint there you should be able to look at the stack trace and see the loop that is happening. It may be a big loop or a little loop. Once you have that you can hopefully work out what is calling back into your equals and fix up that code. Or failing that post the stack trace for us to help debug.

Comment: Chris has a point right up there. Also, you could put a couple of breakpoints: one at `Equals(object x, object y)`, and the other at `IsPropertyChanged(...)`; just to trace the execution flow. With the first breakpoint, you can inspect the variables `x` and `y` and tell what specific types they are. Also to check the call stack on each hit of either method.

Comment: @LeandroTaset I can't put override at the method, if I change new to override I get an error that says: 'There is no suitable method for override' and the variables are of type object{string}

Comment: @Chris Thanks for your advice, it is indeed some kind of infinite loop, I'm going to try to figure it out by myself for now (I'm still a trainee) if I don't find anything I'll get back here tomorrow morning :)

Comment: @Gravinco: StackOverflow exceptions pretty much *always* means a loop, either accidentally like here or because you have a recursive function that recurses too much. And I'm always a fan of figuring it out by yourself. If you do come back tomorrow morning feel free to put a note here pinging me (with @chris). I'm intrigued now. And of course if you figure it out yourself you are encouraged to put an answer to your own question. :)

Comment: Hey @Chris, I found out where the loop is being created, I have put the code in the question as an edit so everyone can see clearly. But my workday is almost over so you probably won't hear from me again until morning :p

Answer (score 1):

> Inside of the **`Equals`** method (or later **`IsPropertyChanged`**), you can't use the **Equals** or any **variant** of it (==, !=)
>   (as it loops back and causes the stack-overflow), **but in such cases you only need to
>   compare against the `null`**, you don't (that I could think of) need to compare the
>   two objects (and you don't really need your custom Equals). So for
>   those cases, just use the `object.ReferenceEquals` - which won't fire
>   off your custom Equals (it uses the entirely different path).

You only have to deal with entity != null type of checks (inside) - usually that's resolved using `object.ReferenceEquals` e.g.

```
!object.ReferenceEquals(entity1, null)
```

instead of the
`entity1 != null`

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit please, I don't really understand what you mean

Comment: sorry, it was just a quick tip - inside of the `IsPropertyChanged` method, you can't use the `Equals` (as it loops back and causes the stack-overflow), but you only need to compare against the `null`, you don't (usually) need to compare the two objects (and you don't really need your custom compare). So for those cases, just use the `object.ReferenceEquals` - which won't fire off your custom Compare (it uses the entirely different path).

Answer (score 0):

I solved the error by adding a depth parameter to the IsPropertyChangedMethod. Now the error doesn't occur anymore but I'm not sure my code works now so I'll get back with that conclusion.

For now, here are the changes I made for resolving the error:

**IsPropertyChanged:**

```
public static bool IsPropertyChanged(PropertyDescriptor pd, object entity1, object entity2, int depth)
    {
        if (depth > 3) return false;
        ...
        ...
        if (!pd.PropertyInfo.PropertyType.IsPrimitive || !(pd.PropertyInfo.PropertyType == typeof(String)))
        {
            return IsComplexChanged(pd, val1, val2, depth);
        }
        ...
        ...
    }
```

Added the parameter and passed it down to IsComplexChanged

**IsComplexChanged:**

```
private static bool IsComplexChanged(PropertyDescriptor pd, object val1, object val2, int depth)
    {
        var comparer = new ConexioEqualityComparer();
        return !comparer.Equals(val1, val2, depth);
    }
```

Passed the parameter down again to Equals

**Equals:**

```
public bool Equals(object x, object y, int depth)
    {
        var xType = x.GetType();
        var yType = y.GetType();
        if (xType != yType) return false;

        return GetPropertiesWithoutKey(xType).All(pd => ConexioComparer.IsPropertyChanged(pd, x, y, ++depth));
    }
```

Add increment and go back to IsPropertyChanged